# Ubuntu 18.04 update-rc.d doesn't do the right thing

Tags: scripts, virtualbox, startup, autostart

I have a newly installed 18.04 system and I am installing VirtualBox on it, with the autostart startup scripts.

The autostart startup scripts correctly list the VirtualBox kernel module as a dependency in the LSB section of the /etc/init.d/ scripts as follows:

/etc/init.d/virtualbox:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       vboxdrv virtualbox
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:  $remote_fs
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Short-Description: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
### END INIT INFO
```

/etc/init.d/vboxautostart-service:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:       vboxautostart-service
# Required-Start: vboxdrv
# Required-Stop:  vboxdrv
# Default-Start:  2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:   0 1 6
# Description:    VirtualBox autostart service
### END INIT INFO
```

However, after I run;

```
sudo update-rc.d vboxautostart-service defaults
```

the /etc/rc*.d/ directories list vboxautostart-service as S01* and K01*.  This causes the dependency between the two to not be honored, and my VirtualBox VMs do not get auto started because the kernel module is not loaded on startup.

For example, here is the dir listing of /etc/rc5.d:

```
S01acpid             S01dbus         S01saned
S01anacron           S01gdm3         S01speech-dispatcher
S01apport            S01grub-common  S01spice-vdagent
S01avahi-daemon      S01irqbalance   S01ssh
S01bluetooth         S01kerneloops   S01unattended-upgrades
S01console-setup.sh  S01ntp          S01uuidd
S01cron              S01plymouth     S01vboxautostart-service
S01cups              S01rsync        S01virtualbox
S01cups-browsed      S01rsyslog      S01whoopsie
```

This works fine on 16.04.  Here's the listing of /etc/rc5.d on 16.04:

```
README            S01rsyslog              S02dbus                   S03grub-common
S01apport         S01unattended-upgrades  S02irqbalance             S03ondemand
S01lvm2-lvmetad   S01uuidd                S02mdadm                  S03plymouth
S01lvm2-lvmpolld  S01virtualbox           S02ntp                    S03rc.local
S01lxcfs          S02acpid                S02rsync
S01lxd            S02atd                  S02ssh
S01open-vm-tools  S02cron                 S02vboxautostart-service
```

Is this broken in 18.04?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. Using the `systemctl` command solved it.

```
sudo systemctl enable vboxautostart-service
```

Comment: The above attempts to port system v scripts but it didn't completely work for me (Ubuntu 18.xx). I switched to systemd and that worked. Unfortunately Init/systemV is legacy so we all need to get off of it. I found the following references helpful in using SystemD: -https://vitux.com/ubuntu-vnc-server/
- https://www.tecmint.com/create-new-service-units-in-systemd/
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units